# Show that unit circle is arcwise connected in $R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, path-connected

**What I have tried**

Consider two arbitrary points on the unit circle, $P = (\cos \theta_1, \sin \theta_1)$ and $Q = (\cos \theta_2, \sin \theta_2)$, where $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are angles in radians.

We can define a function $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ as follows:

$$ f(t) = (\cos((1-t)\theta_1 + t\theta_2), \sin((1-t)\theta_1 + t\theta_2)) $$

Here, $t$ varies from $0$ to $1$. When $t = 0$, $f(0) = P$, and when $t = 1$, $f(1) = Q$. The trigonometric functions $\cos$ and $\sin$ are continuous, and the composition of continuous functions is also continuous. Therefore, $f$ is continuous. So, the function $f$ defines a continuous curve between $P$ and $Q$ on the unit circle.

**Is this correct?**

One of my concern is: do I need to assume that $\theta_1 < \theta_2$?

Comment: No, you don't. The difference between $\theta_1 < \theta_2$ and $\theta_1 > \theta_2$ is that your path goes anticlockwise in the former case and clockwise in the latter. One extra remark is that changing any of the angles by a multiple of $2\pi$ doesn't change the endpoints of the path, but does change the path itself by changing the number of times you wind around the circle.

Comment: Depending on the level of rigor required, you might need one more statement previous to "Therefore, $f$ is continuous".  At the moment, you've stated that $f(t) = (f_1(t), f_2(t))$ and $f_1, f_2$ are continuous.  Do you know why the continuity of $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is implied by the continuity of $f_1,f_2 : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31342/prove-that-the-unit-circle-is-path-connected)..